# htaccess to add directory to relative root requests

Tags: .htaccess

My site is using relative root paths i.e: /_imgs/abc.jpg /_js/stuff.js /product/123/someproduct

As it is on a shared server for testing and I've not assigned a domain to the site as yet the url of the test server is http://server/~testsite/ so a request to http://server/_imgs/abc.jpg  results in a 404.

Is there a rule I can add in htaccess to prepend /~testsite to all url requests?

I've tried using RewriteBase with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines: (untested)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /~testsite/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This would result in all your pages 301 redirecting, but for development, it should be fine.

Comment: unfortunately because of the other rules I have in place that doesn't direct properly.

Answer (score 0):

I always create a new vitualhost and add an entry to my hosts file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
127.0.0.1  example
```

this way the website acts just like on a normal server.